# Trace of operator is twice the trace of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_2\left(\mathbb F\right)$ be fixed. Let $T$ be the linear operator on $V,\;T(A):=PA$. Prove that $\operatorname{trace}(T) = 2\operatorname{trace}(P)$ .

Comment: Find the matrix of T in the standard basis  . . .

Comment: Why should not the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis be $P$?

Comment: For one thing because the dimensions are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trace of linear operator is trace of matrix representation of it. We can take matrices
$$
e_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
e_{12}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
e_{21}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
e_{22}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
as basis. So,
$$
Pe_{11} = \begin{pmatrix}p_{11} & p_{12}\\p_{21} & p_{22}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}p_{11} & 0\\p_{21} & 0\end{pmatrix}=p_{11}e_{11}+p_{21}e_{21}\\
Pe_{12} = \begin{pmatrix}p_{11} & p_{12}\\p_{21} & p_{22}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}0 & p_{11}\\0 & p_{21}\end{pmatrix}=p_{11}e_{12}+p_{21}e_{22}\\
Pe_{21} = \begin{pmatrix}p_{11} & p_{12}\\p_{21} & p_{22}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}p_{12} & 0\\p_{22} & 0\end{pmatrix}=p_{12}e_{11}+p_{22}e_{21}\\
Pe_{22} = \begin{pmatrix}p_{11} & p_{12}\\p_{21} & p_{22}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}0 & p_{12}\\0 & p_{22}\end{pmatrix}=p_{12}e_{21}+p_{22}e_{22}
$$
Matrix of $T$ in this basis ($\{e_{11}, e_{12}, e_{21}, e_{22}\}$) is
$$
[T]=
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & 0 & p_{12} & 0\\
0 & p_{11} & 0 & 0\\
p_{21} & 0 & p_{22} & p_{12}\\
0 & p_{21} & 0 & p_{22}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and $\mathop{\mathrm{tr}} T = 2p_{11}+2p_{22}=2\mathop{\mathrm{tr}} P$.